# Can I access the class field when using is as a template type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I know this code look weird but I'm wondering if there is any way could make it compile.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    enum
    {
        template_class_id = T::class_id
    };
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    enum
    {
        class_id = 0x1234
    };
};
```

And I get such errors:

```
clang++ test.cpp                                            
test.cpp:7:32: error: no member named 'class_id' in 'B'
        template_class_id = T::class_id
                            ~~~^
test.cpp:11:18: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<B>' requested here
class B : public A<B>
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B` is an incomplete type when the base class `A<B>` is instantiated, so `B::class_id` doesn't exist at that point.

To get what you need, you need to delay the instantiation of the `template_class_id` member.

---

One possibility would be to make `template_class_id` a C++14 member variable template:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    template <typename U=T>
    static constexpr int template_class_id = U::class_id;
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    static constexpr int class_id = 0x1234;
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf2571c3917747f5)

Unfortunately that means you need to refer to `template_class_id` as `template_class_id<>`, but it doesn't require any extra types.

---

Another option would be to rely on a traits class:

```
template <typename T> struct ClassId;

template<typename T>
class A {
public:
    static constexpr int template_class_id = ClassId<T>::value;
};

class B;
template <> struct ClassId<B> {
    static constexpr int value = 0x1234;   
};

class B : public A<B> {
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad9976a7cbaed895)

I think this is pretty flexible and doesn't require you to switch to functions. It does mean that the id is lexically outwith your class definition, but I don't think that's a huge issue.

Comment: Your second approach seems usable.

Comment: After lots of testing I found the template_class_id could be available only when the reference to it is `out of` the declaration of class A. I can't use it in the declaration in the class A such as define an enum in class A with the value of template_class_id.

Comment: @jayatubi sure, that's because odr-using `template_class_id` will cause it to be instantiated. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I have lots of the classes in the form like `foo : public wrapper<foo>` to be refactored. I want to make the `wrapper` could access the `class_id` within each `foo` class. If the `wrapper` can't access that I need to add additional code to all the `foo` classes.

Comment: @jayatubi that should be possible so long as you pay attention to what you instantiate in the definition of `wrapper`. E.g. for anything which will be instantiated in the definition, use `ClassId<T>::value`, but you can use `template_class_id` inside of functions.

Comment: @jayatubi feel free to contact me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/496161/tartanllama) if you have problems with this which are not easily expressible in comments.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `class B : public A<B>`. When you are instantiating `A<B>`, `B` is an incomplete type so you can't use `B::class_id`.

The following would work:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr int get_template_class_id() { return T::get_class_id(); }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
public:
    static constexpr int get_class_id() { return 0x1234; }
};
```

This is because member functions don't get instantiated until they are used, and at that point `B` would no longer be incomplete.

Comment: I tried the `constexpr` but it doesn't guaranty it is a real const data and I couldn't use it to initialize enum or use it in a switch case.